# bash scripting error

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
mkdir "UNIX/$line"
done < usernames.lnk
```

I have this error when running the script shown below. I have checked for any spelling errors but both the script and the usernames file is in the same folder yet it cant detect the file.

```
/home/user/Documents/New/taskscript.sh: line 4: usernames.lnk: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

The script will look for the file in the current folder (i.e. the folder in which you *started* it, not the folder in which it is stored).

Try this code instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Determine folder in which this script is stored
BASE=$( cd $( dirname "$0" ) > /dev/null ; pwd )

while read -r line; do
mkdir "UNIX/$line"
done < "$BASE/usernames.lnk"
```

Answer (score 1):

The usernames file needs to be in the current directory when you run the script - having it in the same directory as the script will only work when you call the script from that directory.

You should use a full path in the last line if you want to be able to call that script from anywhere.

Comment: confirmed this worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
./usernames.lnk
```

instead of

```
usernames.lnk
```